# Selenium IDE - script execution time in output

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-ide

Do you know how to check the script execution time in Selenium IDE? What kind of command or option I should use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @kaya Thanks but I need the answer - not a comment like this :)

Comment: My bad, that comment was for another question

Answer (score 6):

I was wondering the same thing, and this is what I came up with.

```
storeEval | new Date().getTime() | startTime

// The rest of your code here

storeEval | new Date().getTime() | endTime
storeEval | (${endTime} - ${startTime}) / 1000 | scriptExecutionTime 
echo      | ${scriptExecutionTime} seconds |
```