# Can I do automated-testing with Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, automated-tests

Chrome Developer Tools are really great when it comes to debugging a web app, but can they be run programmatically somehow? I googled around on the topic, but most of the stuff I can find seem to be slightly outdated.

I have played around quite a bit with jsPerf, and it works really well in smaller tests. I'd like to achieve the same results, but running the real web app in a real browser instead.

Ideally the test suite can handle automated UI interaction with the web app (clicking buttons, submitting text, etc). I'd also like to be able to insert flags in the code, run through the code a given amount of times, and then parse logs etc for the flags to be able to extract the exact timestamps.

Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 2):

I don't  think you Can I do automated with chrome devtools but you can add number of extension to make do the test jobs like this http://selenium-rc.openqa.org/

Comment: That looks good, but can it somehow produce logs etc of the code exception? The automation part seems to be very good, but I am more interested in measuring the execution time etc...

Comment: think this link will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000648/selenium-ide-script-execution-time-in-output